# Sonata admin bundle, manipulate objects

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have 2 entities with one to many relationship project and prototype And I've been looking for a way to list the prototypes that belong to a project in the show action .
here is my project entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Projet
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProjetRepository")
 */

class Projet
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreation", type="date")
 */
private $dateCreation;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Prototype", mappedBy="projet",cascade={"persist"} , orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id"="ASC"})
 */
protected $prototypes;


public function __construct()
{   
    $this->prototypes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->dateCreation =  new \DateTime("now");
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 * @return Projet
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

public function __toString()
{
return $this->getNom();
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Projet
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
 * @return Projet
 */
public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
{
    $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreation
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateCreation()
{
    return $this->dateCreation;
}


public function setPrototypes($prototypes)
{
if (count($prototypes) > 0) {
    foreach ($prototypes as $i) {
        $this->addPrototypes($i);
    }
}

return $this;
}

/**
 * Add prototypes
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Prototype $prototypes
 * @return Projet
 */
public function addPrototypes(\AppBundle\Entity\Prototype $prototypes)
{
$this->prototypes[]= $prototypes;
return $this;
}

public function addPrototype(\AppBundle\Entity\Prototype $prototype)
{
$prototype->setProjet($this);
$this->prototypes->add($prototype);
}


/**
 * Remove prototypes
 *
 * @param \AppBunble\Entity\Prototype $prototypes
 */
public function removePrototypes(\AppBundle\Entity\Prototype $prototypes)
{
$this->prototypes->removeElement($prototypes);
}



/**
 * Get prototypes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */

public function getPrototypes()
{
return $this->prototypes;
}



}
```

and here is my prototype entity

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Prototype
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\PrototypeRepository")
 */
class Prototype
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nom;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreation", type="date")
 */
private $dateCreation;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Projet", inversedBy="prototypes")
 * @ORM\joinColumn(name="projet_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $projet;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * Get nom
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

public function __toString()
{
return $this->getNom();
}

/**
 * Set nom
 *
 * @param string $nom
 * @return Prototype
 */
public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 * @return Prototype
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
 * @return Prototype
 */
public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
{
    $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreation
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getDateCreation()
{
    return $this->dateCreation;
}




/**
 * Set projet
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Projet $projet
 * @return Prototype
 */
public function setProjet(\AppBundle\Entity\Projet $projet = null)
{
    $this->projet = $projet;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get projet
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Projet 
 */
public function getProjet()
{
    return $this->projet;
}
}
```

In my projetAdmin I can show in the ShowAction the prototypes :
here is projetAdmin :

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;


class ProjetAdmin extends Admin
{   

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('nom', 'text', array('label' => 'Nom'))
        ->add('description','text',array('label'=>'Description'))
        ->add('dateCreation', 'date', array('label' => 'Date de création'))


        ;
}

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('dateCreation')

    ;
}


protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper

        ->add('nom')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('dateCreation')
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        )
        )

    ;
}



protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper

    ->add('prototypes')


;

}



}
```

I get the prototypes ( names )

But I would like to "list" the prototypes that belong to the project like the list view ( name , description of the prototype...)

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve the problem but still I feel it's not the better way 
I created a controller and overrided the showAction

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class CRUDController extends Controller
{

    public function showAction($id = null)
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_app_prototype_list', array(
        'filter[projet__id][value]'=>$id
    )));
    }
}
```

Then I get a list of prototypes that belong to a project.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define the template for your `prototypes` field in `showMapper`

```
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper ->add('prototypes',null, array('template' => 'NamespaceYourBundle::Admin/prototypes.html.twig'));

}
```

Create `Admin` folder in your bundle's resources folder and create `prototypes.html.twig` file ,extend your twig template with sonata's  `base_show_field.html.twig` template and in `{% block field %}` define your own markup looping through all related prototypes

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if object.getPrototypes() is not empty %}
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr class="sonata-ba-list-field-header">
            <th class="sonata-ba-list-field-header-text">Nom</th>
            <th class="sonata-ba-list-field-header-text">Description</th>
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for prototype in object.getPrototypes() %}
            <tr>
                <td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-text">{{ prototype.getNom() }}</td>
                <td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-text">{{ prototype.getDescription() }}</td>
                ...
                ...
                ...
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            </table>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I will try and see if it will resolve my problem