# Show One To Many relationship in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to show the one-to-many relationshop entity in the sonata admin's show action. I found answer to my problem at ("[Sonata admin bundle, manipulate objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744070/sonata-admin-bundle-manipulate-objects/31765931#31765931)"). I try to implement @M Khalid Junaid's solution but I get an error "**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: nl2br() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given") in SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig at line 13.**"

Did anyone here face this problem before?

GroupParticipant.php

```
class GroupRepresentive {
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupParticipant", mappedBy="representive", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    public $participant;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->participant = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    ...}
```

GroupRepresentativeAdmin.php

```
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
        {
            $showMapper
                ->add('name')
                ->add('eventTitle')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('person')
                ->add('payment.paymentType')
                ->add('payment.bank')
                ->add('payment.userAccountNumber')
                ->add('payment.referenceNumber')
                ->add('payment.paymentAt')
                ->end()
                ->with('Participant')
                ->add('participant', 'null', array(
                    'template' => 'AppBundle::Admin/groupParticipant.html.twig'
                ))
            ;

        }
```

groupParticipant.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig' %}
{% block field %}
    {% spaceless %}

    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

I put the custom template at

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you didn't really extend the

`SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig`

try this

```
    {% block field %}
         {# show a field of your entity for example the name #}
         {{value.name}}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: My file path seems like have some mistake so it actually didnt use the custom template that I created. Is that my file path correct? @elkorchi-anas

Comment: the path is correct keep it like it is, but the location of your template is incorrect, put the admin directory in views directory not in the resources dir so you will have something like this /ressources/views/Admin/group_Participant.html.twig

Answer (score 0):

Though the previous answer have been accepted, I'm providing solution for users who are using Symfony 4 and Symfony 3.4 (Symfony Flex).

Field in Admin class must be like:

GroupRepresentativeAdmin.php

```
->add('participant', 'null', array(
                    'template' => 'folderName/fileName.html.twig'
                ));
```

Note that the folder must be in your **templates** directory. The path to your twig file must be **templates/folderName/fileName.html.twig**

The content in twig file must be like:

fileName.html.twig

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    {% spaceless %}
           //Your custom operation
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```